# Linked resources in Eclipse in multiple workspaces and OSs

Tags: eclipse, variables, windows-7, linked-list, resources

I have some Eclipse projects that need to run on multiple machines and OSs.
All the projects share a data folder, so the most logical thing to do is a workspace linked resource pointing to that folder. So I set a `DATA_DIR` linked resource on every workspace,  e.g. `c:\data` on Windows, `/home/mulone/data` on Unix/Mac, etc.
Then in the `.project` file of each project I manually added the following:

```
<linkedResources>
   <link>
     <name>data.txt</name>
     <type>1</type>
     <location>${DATA_DIR}/data.txt</location>
   </link>         
</linkedResources>
```

The strange thing is that works perfectly on Mac/Linux, but on Windows7 I get the following error: `Could not open the editor: Must specify a URI scheme:$%7BDATA_DIR%7D/data.txt`

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.

Mulone

Comment: related post: http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Java/comp.lang.java.programmer/2007-05/msg01965.html

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the .project file programmatically using: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.setDescription(..) - basically setting the IProjectDescription which is the exact mapping of the .project file.